# UINavigationBar set background image center swift..?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm placing the background image this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

but, repeat the image. No I want it to be repeated to me and Put it center.. ?

Comment: Make sure the image is in the correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to fix it using UIAppearance and UIImage API:

```
// disable image stretching by defining left and top caps. 
let navbarImage = image.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 1, topCapHeight: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navbarImage, for: .default)
```

Example before:
[image]

and after the fix:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with below `method` which worked for me.

```
        var headerview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 44))            
        let imgview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 75, y: 0, width: 150, height: 44))
        imgview.image = UIImage(named: "ImageName")
        imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        headerview.addSubview(imgview)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = headerview
```